# how to retrieve templates for different user accounts

Tags: api, templates, docusignapi

I have one account in docusign which has 3 users for it. We have a requirement of retrieving templates of users for that account. The [Template:List](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/reference/Templates/Templates/list) API is retrieving all the templates of the account. There is also one path parameter named **user_id** but it is not retrieving the templates of particular user account instead it is retrieving all templates.
Is there any way through Rest API we will retrieve list of templates of user account?
If there Please provide the Rest API details or link.

Answer (score 0):

From my own testing, it appears you're right. This could be a bug, I'm not sure and I'll follow up but this may take time.
Two possible workaround.

1. Make the API call in the context of the user that you wish you get templates. Basically, you'll need to obtain an accessToken for the API for that user. With JWT that is very simple, just use the userID when you ask for the token (but you do have to get consent).
2. Filter the list of templates you get. The list does include information about the owner of the template (again, userID) but you'll get all of them and have to do the work to find the ones you want.

(Update 5/26/2020: confirmed with engineering this is a bug. It is tracked under TT-3290).

(Update 6/23/2020: bug was resolved, will be deployed shortly)